# Get author's avatar inside a MySQL query in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am fetching authors ID, points from wp_cp table using following code in my WordPress site and it works perfectly. Which I am trying now is to get users avatar beside users ID. How I can get users avatar inside the code?

```
<?php

  global $wpdb;
  /* wpdb class should not be called directly.global $wpdb variable is an    instantiation of the class already set up to talk to the WordPress database */ 

  $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT uid,sum(points) as pt FROM wp_cp   where timestamp between '2015-12-12' and '2015-12-31' group by uid  "); /*mulitple row results can be pulled from the database with get_results function and outputs an object which is stored in $result */

  //echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
  /* If you require you may print and view the contents of $result object */

  echo "uid"."  "."pt"."<br><br>";



  foreach($result as $row)
  {

  echo $row->uid."  ".$row->pt."<br>";

  }
  /* Print the contents of $result looping through each row returned in the result */

 ?>
```

Comment: What is wp_cp? Is that a plugin database table? There's usually a way to do these types of things without writing raw database queries in WordPress.

Comment: yes it is a plugin database table.I need to use this table to get my custom data but finding no way to get the avator

Comment: Is `uid` saved with the same value as the user's ID in the wp_users table?

Comment: yes uid is saved with the same value as the user's ID

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the following code to get user avatar inside the foreach loop.

```
echo get_avatar( $row->uid );
```

Since you are asking for size, you can add a parameter to this function.

`echo get_avatar( $row->uid, 64 ); // So the avatar size will be 64px X 64 px.`

For further reference check this [URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar)

Comment: Hi thanks, it works like a charm.How can I use the avator size option in the same code

Comment: ok got it <?php echo get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt, $args ); ?>  Thanks

Comment: what is the plugin you are currently using?

Comment: Is [Cubepoints](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cubepoints/) supports in latest wp version?

Comment: I don't know I am using an old version in a test hosting

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `uid` field (which matches the user's ID in wp_users), pass it into the get_avatar function:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

Comment: yes I have tried but it messed the code.Can u provide the code example pls inside my code above